# how to record audio only for 1 min?

Tags: android, audio, timer, media-player, record

in my android app , i need to record audio for only 1 min? can any one help me to record audio for a certain amount of time? i ve written a code for recording audio and it will stop only when the stop button is pressed but i need to stop recording automatically after 1 min...

here my code .. but it doesnt work

```
       try {
             recorder.prepare();

           recorder.start();
         //Declare the timer

           Timer t = new Timer();
           //Set the schedule function and rate
           t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

               @Override
               public void run() {

                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(AudioRecordingActivity.this, "record successfullly ",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    i1=i1+1;
                        }

                    });


                   //Called each time when 1000 milliseconds (1 second) (the period parameter)
               }

           },
           //Set how long before to start calling the TimerTask (in milliseconds)
           0,
           //Set the amount of time between each execution (in milliseconds)
           10*1000);

           if (null != recorder) {
            recorder.stop();
            recorder.reset();
            recorder.release();

            recorder = null;
            Toast.makeText(AudioRecordingActivity.this, "record successfullly",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           }

                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: why not simulate the click event for the button after 1 min?

Comment: use this method recorder.setMaxDuration();

Comment: but i dont want that stop button instead it will stop recording after 1 min automatically ... suggest any code

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
recorder.start();
   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
        recorder.stop();
         }
                }, 60000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `recorder.setMaxDuration(60*1000);`
Or, if you need to do this repeatetly, use above answer, but add

```
if (null == recorder)
{
   recorder = new MediaRecorder();
} else recorder.reset();
```

This approach more likely :)

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setOutputFile(getFilename());
recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);
try {
  recorder.prepare();
  recorder.start();

 new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
   public void run() {
    if (null != recorder) {
      recorder.stop();
      recorder.reset();
      recorder.release();
      recorder = null;

  }
});
}
}, 60000);
}
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```